# Get non empty Sub Collections in Firestore using Query class

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get non empty Rooms from Buildings Collection from Firebase Firestore ( Using Flutter Framework):

```
Query _queryRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Buildings')
    .where("isActive", isEqualTo: true)
    .where("Rooms", isNotEqualTo : null);
```

But I am not getting any collections Even though there are few Rooms sub collection records exist in Buildings.

Adding Screenshot for reference-

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the Firebase console of one of the documents you expect to be returned by this query? Can you also show the minimal code to actually read the database that reproduces the problem, for example that logs the query results (or lack thereof)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - Thanks! Added screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries in Firestore work on a single collection, or on a group of collections of the same name. There is no way to query your `Buildings` documents on the existence of or values in their `Rooms` subcollection.

The typical workaround is to store a `RoomCount` field in each `Buildings` document, and keep that up to date as you add/remove rooms. With that in place you can query:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Buildings')
    .where("isActive", isEqualTo: true)
    .where("RoomCount", isGreaterThan: 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Append .get() at the end of your query. [Here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#querying) you can read more about most common use cases of working with firebase via flutter.